# JSLint - ignore missing function name

Tags: javascript, jslint

I am trying to evaluate an anonymous JavaScript function using JSLint. However, JSLint fails evaluating it because the function is missing a name. What option can I set to allow JSLint to ignore that error?

Something like:

```
function(test) {
    return;
}
```

Results in:

```
Missing name in function statement.
function(test) {
```

**EDIT**: To clarify, the anonymous function will be used as a view for CouchDB. I want to ensure that the syntax is correct before it hits the DB.

Comment: It's not just a jsLint issue. It's a SyntaxError, so your code won't run at all. If you want to invoke it in place, do `(function(test) { return; })()`, though I don't see the point. If you're not going to invoke it, then there's no point to the anonymous function.

Comment: It does have a point -- the query will used as a map function for CouchDB. I want to evaluate the syntax of the function before it hits the DB.

Comment: So you're saying it's not in a program, but you just want to use jsLint to validate it? If so, then why not just give it a name or assign it to a variable? You can't expect a validator to turn a blind eye to what it could only see as broken code.

Comment: Assigning to a variable would be the best option then. As for your last comment, I would expect it to assume that JSLint would allow anonymous functions when I can set `couch: true` in the options for JSLint to assume for CouchDb.

Comment: That option only defines the globals that would be found in the CouchDB environment AFAIK. The syntax validator would be otherwise the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a JavaScript function non-anonymous by using one of the following techniques:

1. Give the function a name:

   ```
   function myFunction(test) {
       return;
   }
   ```
2. Assign the function to a variable:

   ```
   var myFunction = function(test) {
       return;
   }
   ```
3. In fact, you can combine both approaches, but i wouldn't recommend that:

   ```
   var myFunction = function myFunction(test) {
       return;
   }
   ```

Comment: In the case of CouchDB, I would assume the first is the only valid solution, given that when the functions are (effectively) assigned to a variable.